# Why SparkSession class of pyspark is in pyspark.sql not pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

As the official documents of Spark [Starting Point: SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#starting-point-sparksession) puts"The entry point into all functionality in Spark is the SparkSession class."

So, I'm wodering why in pyspark the SparkSession is imported from pyspark.sql not pyspark itself. My logic is since SparkSession is the entry point of all fuctionality in Spark (SparkSql, SparkStreaming, SparkMLib, SparkGraphX, etc.), doesn't it make more sense to import SparkSession from spark but not spark.sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily because `pyspark` is used for [Spark Core](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.html) - RDD-based APIs that were existing in Spark from the beginning, and `SparkSession` (originally as `SQLContext`) was added as a part of Spark SQL (original [announcement](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2014/03/26/spark-sql-manipulating-structured-data-using-spark-2.html)).